# Why am I getting "Unsupported Major Minor Version 52.0" compile time error?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring project running on JRE 8.0. For some reason, in my application context XML file, I'm getting the following error for the tag:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.controller" />
```

Error:

```
Error occured processing XML 'com/myproject/controller/protocol/FetchResponseBody : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0'. See Error Log for more details   servlet-context.xml /eyecontrol/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring  line 19 Spring Beans Problem
```

The class in question is simply an annotation as follow:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@ResponseBody
public @interface FetchResponseBody {

}
```

The  thing is, I'm only getting this error on my PC. My laptop does not have this error at all. Also, regardless of this compile time "error", I do not seem to have any issues actually running it whether through eclipse or through the terminal.

The run-as configuration is selected to JRE8.0 and the build path contains this same JRE. This issue doesn't actually hinder progress but is sure as hall annoying to see!

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you look at System properties to ensure you're not using another JVM ? How do you run your app ? From an IDE, command-line, etc ?

Comment: Are you using  eclipse? What's your compiler compliance level? You can see it in your project properties.

Comment: I run this through STS (eclipse). It runs without issue, it's just the "Problems" window at the bottom of the IDE that complains about it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project in package explorer(In Eclipse)

Java Compiler -> Check if compiler compliance level is set to 1.8

Comment: Yes, it's already set to 1.8, the run as configuration is also set to JRE 8.0, the project facets has Java set to 1.8, and the maven pom file has the compiler verison, source, and target all set to 8.

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, I just updated my STS (eclipse) and the issue went away. Thanks for the other responses though.